# Why are most of the from localeconv basically empty?

Tags: php, locale

I'm running PHP 5.3.0, Apache 2.2.11 on Windows 7 and I tried to run this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.UTF-8');
print_r(localeconv());
```

And got this:

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] => 
    [int_curr_symbol] => 
    [currency_symbol] => 
    [mon_decimal_point] => 
    [mon_thousands_sep] => 
    [positive_sign] => 
    [negative_sign] => 
    [int_frac_digits] => 127
    [frac_digits] => 127
    [p_cs_precedes] => 127
    [p_sep_by_space] => 127
    [n_cs_precedes] => 127
    [n_sep_by_space] => 127
    [p_sign_posn] => 127
    [n_sign_posn] => 127
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What is going on here? Why are basically all the values empty or strange?

Comment: Hmm, Windows problem? Looks better on OS X.

Comment: Yeah, looked better on my webhost which is running on Unix too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently locales are named differently on Windows... *sigh*... This fixed it:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.UTF-8', 'sve');
```

Comment: How do I set the locale manually in Environment Variables on Windows?

Comment: @JimmyIlenloa: Not sure what you're asking here... If you mean for PHP, I don't think you do. Think you use the php.ini file, wherever it's located for you. If you mean for Windows itself, use the regular control panel stuff.

Answer (score 0):

@Svish

Well, the reason is that locales are platform dependent.
From what I've come to notice, Linux machines use an underscore as their *separator*.
Yet, Windows machines use a dash as their separator.

For example;-

**Platform**    | **Preferred locale chosen by platform**

Linux          | sv_SE

Windows     | sv-SE

The good thing is that `setlocale()` supports adding fallback *locales*.

For example;

```
$locale = 'sv_SE';

// Replace underscores with dashes for the fallback locale.
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . '.UTF-8',
 str_replace('_', '-', $locale) . '.UTF-8');
print_r(localeconv());

// Output:

// Array
// (
//     [decimal_point] => ,
//     [thousands_sep] =>  
//     [int_curr_symbol] => SEK
//     [currency_symbol] => kr
//     [mon_decimal_point] => ,
//     [mon_thousands_sep] =>  
//     [positive_sign] =>
//     [negative_sign] => -
//     [int_frac_digits] => 2
//     [frac_digits] => 2
//     [p_cs_precedes] => 0
//     [p_sep_by_space] => 1
//     [n_cs_precedes] => 0
//     [n_sep_by_space] => 1
//     [p_sign_posn] => 1
//     [n_sign_posn] => 1
//     [grouping] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 3
//         )

//     [mon_grouping] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 3
//         )

// )
```

The platform will automatically choose the locale it prefers/supports.

You can easily view what locale has been preferred by the platform. i.e

```
/* try different possible locale names for german */
$loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL,  'de_DE', 'de-DE');
echo "Preferred locale for german on this system is '$loc_de'";

// Output:
// Preferred locale for german on this system is 'de-DE'
```

For more details, check out:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php